# Bundler cant read autoprefixer-rails-6.0.3.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bundler is throwing an error `could not read the gem` & that `it may be corrupted.`

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/pragadeesh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-6.0.3.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (6.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '6.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

i dont know how to resolve this problem ? please help me out.

Comment: `gem uninstall autoprefixer-rails` and then `gem install autoprefixer-rails`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ rm -f /home/pragadeesh/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/autoprefixer-rails-6.0.3.gem
$ gem install autoprefixer-rails
```